# paapi5_python_sdk.models not found

Tags: python

I was trying to set up a bot for Amazon offers. However, when starting the bot, despite having installed all the requirements, I am returned the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 4, in <module> from amazon_api import search_items

File "/ home / Alex / Desktop / AmazonOffers-TelegramBot
main / amazon_api.py ", line 2, in <module> from paapi5_python_sdk.models.partner_type import PartnerType ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paapi5_python_sdk.models'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you put a `__init__.py` file in models folder? Wait, you did not write the models module? Then it would seem there is something wrong with the installation